# Show js alert in error message in db connection function in php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, class

Hi i have create a function in **db class**

```
FUNCTION DB_Class($dbname, $username, $password) {
          $this->db = MYSQL_CONNECT ('localhost', $username, $password)
           or DIE ("Unable to connect to Database Server");

          MYSQL_SELECT_DB ($dbname, $this->db) or DIE ("Could not select database");
     }
```

how can i show the error message in js **alert** in this function on **connection** **fails**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
<?php
    FUNCTION DB_Class($dbname, $username, $password) {
        $this->db = MYSQL_CONNECT ('localhost', $username, $password);

        if (!$this->db)
            echo '<script> alert("Connection error1"); </script>';

        if (!MYSQL_SELECT_DB ($dbname, $this->db))
            echo '<script> alert("Connection error2"); </script>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to stop your connection function from using die(). trigger_error() dump out the error  without killing the script:

```
function DB_Class($dbname, $username, $password) {

    $this->db = mysql_connect ('localhost', $username, $password) 
            or trigger_error (mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db ($dbname, $this->db) 
            or trigger_error ("Could not select database");
}
```

Then, on your page, you'll need to access the $db property of your database wrapper class (I'm assuming that your code is apart of some sort of customer DB wrapper class):

```
if(!is_resource($databaseObject->db)){
    echo '<script>alert("Unable to connect to Database Server!");</script>';
}
```